# how to split a string into diferent segments of 2 words where the first word of the second segment repeats the last word of the first

Tags: python, string, split, segment

I am trying to figure out how to split a string into segments of 2 words where the first word of the second segment repeats the last word of the first. (in Python 2)For example, "hi i am a human named joe norman" should slit into "hi i", "i am", "am joe", "joe norman". I have the following code:

```
txt = raw_input("")

newtxt = txt.split(" ")
```

the problem with this is that it splits txt by each space, not every other. I would like to use no libraries. Thank you.

Comment: Correct your example bud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
t = "hi i am a human named joe norman"
words = t.split()

result = list(zip(words, words[1:]))

for first, second in result:
    print("{} {}".format(first, second))
```

**Output**

```
hi i
i am
am a
a human
human named
named joe
joe norman
```

Answer (score 0):

Option with listcomp:

```
s = "hi i am a human named joe norman"
s = s.split()

l = [f'{i} {s[num + 1]}' for num, i in enumerate(s)
    if num + 1 < len(s)]

print(l) #['hi i', 'i am', 'am a', 'a human', 'human named', 'named joe', 'joe norman']
```

Answer (score 0):

for completeness, a few more options:

the first version is loosely based on [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def pairs1(words):
    w2 = iter(words)
    next(w2, None)
    return zip(words, w2)
```

it's nice because the slice (`words[1:]`) in Daniel's code above creates a copy of the `words` list which could be big, while all that is needed is an iterator at a "different" position

an another version using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

```
def pairs2(words):
    for i in range(1, len(words)):
        yield (words[i-1], words[i])
```

which is similar to Mykola's but feels nicer to me.  Of course either could be rewritten to use list comprehensions, e.g:

```
l = [f'{words[i-1]} {words[i]}' for i in range(1, len(words))]
```

is equivalent to:

```
l = [f'{w} {x}' for w, x in pairs2(words)]
```